# C# WPF Задание фона формы из ресурса проекта

Tags: c#, wpf

разрабатываю приложение, но мне необходимо из ресурсов достать изображение по средством языка C# без xaml. XAML не подходит из-за того, что в будущем путь к картинки будет динамическим и само изображение сможет загружать пользователь, но при отсутствии заданного фона программа сама из ресурсов достанет картинку. В итоге получается, что вместо картинки черный фон, но не могу понять из-за чего, ведь все построено вроде логично, но не прокатывает. Сам файл "Background" имеет действие при сборке "Resource" и имеет расширение jpg.

Основной класс (Привязанный к xaml интерфейсу):

```
WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush()
{
    ImageSource = Source.Image.ConvertBitmapToImageSource(Properties.Resources.Background),
};

this.Background = imageBrush;
```

Класс, отвечающий за преобразование ресурса:

```
public static ImageSource ConvertBitmapToImageSource(Bitmap value)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        value.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
        img.BeginInit();
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); img.StreamSource = ms;
        img.EndInit();
        return img;
    }
}
```

Comment: `XAML не подходит из-за того, что в будущем путь к картинки будет динамическим` - вы очень сильно недооцениваете XAML. У привязок например есть свойства, которые задаются при пустом/нулевом значение. Вам достаточно сделать грамотную привязку к `string` свойству, сделать изображение "заглушку" и установить ее на null привязку.

Comment: Спасибо, тогда более подробно ознакомлюсь с данными возможностями Xaml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XAML в вашей задаче как раз и нужен, еще как!

- Загрузим предположим изображение "заглушку" в ресурсы, просто перетаскиваем в проект и все по умолчанию там должно быть как надо. У меня это будет изображение с названием `image-not-found.png` в корне проекта.
- Дальше в ресурсах укажем `BitmapImage` с нужным изображением. Я для простоты и скорости написания примера укажу это прям в ресурсах главного окна:

  ```
  <Window.Resources>
      <BitmapImage x:Key="NotFoundImage" UriSource="image-not-found.png" />
  </Window.Resources>
  ```
- Теперь нам нужно создать свойство, которое будет содержать путь к нужному изображению и так, как оно будет обновляться, нам нужно реализовать еще и `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

  - Добавляем события INPC:

    ```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
    ```
  - Добавляем публичное `string` свойство:

    ```
    private string backgroundPath;
    public string BackgroundPath
    {
        get => backgroundPath;
        set
        {
            backgroundPath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    ```
  - Указываем `DataContext` к классу, где реализовали свойство (у меня это само окно (опять же скорость и все дела, делать там не стоит!):

    ```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
    ```
- Теперь вернемся к XAML и сделаем там простенький интерфейс:

  ```
  <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition/>
          <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding BackgroundPath, FallbackValue={StaticResource NotFoundImage}}" Width="500" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
      <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding BackgroundPath, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1"/>
  </Grid>
  ```

Тут как видите текстовое поле привязано к созданному свойству и изображение. У изображения установлен `FallbackValue`, который при проблемах с установкой значения выдаст нам картинку из ресурсов. Тут можно также указать и `TargetNullValue={StaticResource NotFoundImage}`, тогда "заглушка" будет устанавливаться еще и тогда, когда привязанное свойство будет `NULL`.

Хорошо, можем теперь запускать и тестировать:

[image: Result]

Вот и все. Как видите без всяких проверок и большого кода с конветациями, мы привязали путь к изображению и его "заглушку" из ресурсов.