# Динамическое задание заднего фона формы C# WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml

B моем приложении присутствует возможность динамического задания заднего фона. Само изображение хранится переменной, которая находится в другом классе (Документе). Недавно перешел с `WinForms` на `WPF` и все довольно непривычно. Xочется все писать кодом, но фишка данной технологии - это XAML: которое позволяет значительно сократить код приложения и добавить понятности структуры.

Вопрос: Как реализовать динамическое задание заднего фона формы C# WPF XAML?

Comment: что значит `динамический фон формы` и как он должен работать? Кто его задает? Где он хранится? Он применется ко всем окнам или к конкретрому? Вы используете MVVM?

Comment: Внесу немного ясности. При запуске приложения срабатывает класс на десериализацию JSON файла. В данном документе хранится путь к картинке. Поле путь к изображению конвертируется в ImageSource. (или картинка может браться из БД в виде последовательности бит) И уже после форма берет данную картинку. Также есть возможность ручного выбора изображения при помощи класса openfiledialog. Данный фон присваивается к конкретному. MVVM не используется

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1044235/220553

Comment: В таком случае вот это `MVVM не используется` станет вашей первой и главной проблемой. Практически по любому вопросу, если вы пишете что то сложнее, чем hello, world, вам будут указвать на отсутсвие MVVM. Что бы я сделал - я бы создал модель и вью-модель, которые хранят все, что нужно, для создания ImageSource, и на представлении использовал бы биндинг и конвертер для того, чтобы мою вью-модель конвертировать уже в ImageSource и прилепить туда, куда надо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну вот, я автору про MVVM, а вы ему предложили биндить окно на себя :)

Comment: @tym32167 Я лишь дал самый базовый вариант того, как это правильно реализовать. Про `DataContext` я в том ответе вроде сделал пометку, что это не правильно. Так я вообще всем советую глянуть [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562578/%d0%a2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-mvvm-app-xaml-cs-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) ответ)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ пфф, по [ответам Влада](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/379331/179763) уже вообще можно книги писать )